# Image goes on the header without header moving down

Tags: html, css

I am interested in putting my hard hat icon partially "on top" of my header without the header container moving down. Sorry for the poor description; here's a (horrible, I'm not a decent graphics designer) basic image of what I mean:

[image: Image1]

Any assistance would be appreciated. Fiddle around with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QFV48/

```
.container {
    width: 570px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

.hard_hat {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #1173F2;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is make your container div position: relative and then absolutely position your image. Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/QFV48/3/

```
.container {
    width: 570px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 75px;
    position: relative;
}

.hard_hat {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend changing the hard hat image to a CSS background image, since it's not important to the content.

Remove the IMG and .hard_hat selector in your CSS, then add the following:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
}

#header:after {
    background: url('//cl.ly/image/1d3v1S3K0u2L/hard-hat.png') no-repeat;
    content:"";
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr5Rm/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust its margins to move it "into" the header, and off to the left a bit:

```
.hard_hat {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QFV48/5/

Comment: Thank you, although I believe I'll go with the previous one as I am able to understand it a bit better. Much obliged!